# X11 blank vs dpms off

Tags: x11, dpms

I've been playing around with the dpms/blanking settings on a version of Linux built via yocto.

Something odd I've noticed is that "blank" and "dpms off" both put the monitor to sleep.  I had thought blanking would just, well, blank the screen, and not actually power off the monitor.  Am I mistaken?

Blanking test:

```
$ xset s blank
$ xset s activate
```

DPMS test

```
$ xset dpms force off
```

What I'd like is to just blank the screen on a short interval and then actually power off the monitor after a longer interval.  Perhaps I should look at a minimal black screensaver instead of using the built in blank.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:

If you're looking for a minimalistic screen locker & saver (I think locking is more important than saving), be sure to look into

> http://tools.suckless.org/slock/

To my knowledge it doesn't know about a grace period before locking, but perhaps you can wrap `slock` into a shell script to do that.

Comment: I don't really need locking, but that's a great reference.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting further, it looks like:

```
$ xset s noblank
$ xset s 600 600
```

Will do what I want.  This seems to set the X screensaver to the internal one, which creates a black window, instead of blanking the screen, and timeout after ten minutes.